# How to solve UnicodeDecodeError in Python when executing Make Valid LWGEOM algorithm in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, invalid-data

I'm trying to fix some invalid geometries using the Make Valid LWGEOM algorithm in QGIS 2.8.3 processing toolbox but a Python error occurs:

Errore durante l'esecuzione di codice Python:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Angelo/.qgis2/python/plugins\processing\gui\AlgorithmDialog.py", line 200, in accept
    if runalg(self.alg, self):
  File "C:/Users/Angelo/.qgis2/python/plugins\processing\gui\AlgorithmExecutor.py", line 51, in runalg
    alg.execute(progress)
  File "C:/Users/Angelo/.qgis2/python/plugins\processing\core\GeoAlgorithm.py", line 248, in execute
    str(e) + self.tr('\nSee log for more details'))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe8 in position 19: ordinal not in range(128)

Versione Python:
2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]

Versione di QGIS:
2.8.3-Wien Wien, 313a6bc

Percorso Python: ['C:/Users/Angelo/.qgis2/python/plugins\processinglwgeomprovider', 'C:/Users/Angelo/.qgis2/python/plugins\processing', 'C:/PROGRA~1/QGISWI~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python', u'C:/Users/Angelo/.qgis2/python', u'C:/Users/Angelo/.qgis2/python/plugins', 'C:/PROGRA~1/QGISWI~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado-4.0.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\backports.ssl_match_hostname-3.4.0.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\certifi-14.05.14-py2.7.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\bin\python27.zip', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\DLLs', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\bin', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytz-2012j-py2.7.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\six-1.3.0-py2.7.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd-0.9.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt-0.7.5-py2.7.egg', u'C:/Users/Angelo/.qgis2//python', 'C:\Users\Angelo\.qgis2\python\plugins\mmqgis/forms', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\qgis-ltr\python\plugins\fTools\tools']

How can I fix it? Or which other method could I use to fix the invalid geometries? I have to fix some shapefiles which may contain hundreds of invalid ones so I can't do it manually... I also tried the same procedure in QGIS 2.10.1 but the same error occurs...

Comment: this seems a Procesing Toolbox bug simply to fix changing str(e) with relative unicode encoding... It does not seems related with the LWGEOM provider. Please open qgis tiket following these instructions https://hub.qgis.org/wiki/17/Bugreports

Comment: as workaround probably in the message of the exception there are filenames or directories with non ascii chars like accents and so on => remove accents or 'strange' chars... I don't imagine could be an exception related with record name.

Comment: @LuigiPirelli I edited the question to add the full error message, I checked the chars how you suggested to me but I can't see any non-ascii char, if I'm not wrong...

Comment: may you look for and report here the processing log error message? in the code, before rising it, the exception message is wrote in the processing log.

Comment: That exception happen where there is an algorithm exception (not related with GeoAlgorithm execution). I remember there where some report about failure of MakeValid in some record conditions.... btw, share the log message

Comment: @LuigiPirelli the error occurs as I click on the Run button on the Make valid processing window. The Python error window immediately pops up and contains exactly what I wrote in the question. At this point, the only thing I can read in the Log tab of the Make valid processing window is "Starting Make valid algorithm..." but QGIS seems not executing it. Opening the History and Log window in the Processing menù, I can see a chronology where I can re-open a Python error window which contains the exact same error message that popped up when I clicked on the Run button...

Comment: @LuigiPirelli I hope to have been clear, and sorry if I couldn't have understood what you meant talking about the log message...

Comment: the provider just pass the call to lwgeom lib loaded dinamically. So I suggest A) test MakeValid inside Postgis to jump all the processing and provider overhead B) isolate a test data set that replicate the error and share it to test locally... It's necessary also to share platform details